# How does electrostatic field affect liquid metal?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, metals

I am currently studying electromigration in liquid metals. According to studies that have been done for electromigration in liquid metals, the metal ions are affected by the electrostatic force and therefore can move to the cathode/anode. The force that moves the metal atoms to the electrode is affected by the charge of the metal ion.

However, my professor told me that in liquid state metal atoms should be neutral/not ionized. So how exactly does an electrostatic field affect the metal atoms or cause atomic movement in this case?

Comment: You should read this page first : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasma_(physics)

Comment: @M06-2x It seems that just linking the plasma wikipedia page is really unhelpful. I understand your point, that there will be some free charges in the metal which might in some ways act like a plasma. But given that we are not talking about a plasma, but liquid metal, the applicable bits of that page will be few and far between, and the page is _really_ long.

Comment: Worth a look at and the references therein? [Unconventional hydrodynamics of hybrid fluid made of liquid metals and aqueous solution under applied fields](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/323773618_Unconventional_hydrodynamics_of_hybrid_fluid_made_of_liquid_metals_and_aqueous_solution_under_applied_fields)